# How to continue and discard the computation in the loop by using MATLAB?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, for-loop, size

How to continue and stop in the loop by using MATLAB.

I want to compare the original image with 100 images with many different sizes.
If the size is same size, continue computation with go on the Matlab code. Otherwise, if the images are not same size, we will discard the database image and do not go on with the Matlab code, and start again with next image. Please help me how to write the Matlab code for this situation.

Thank you very much

Comment: use "continue" to go to next iteration of the loop, http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/continue.html

Answer (score 1):

How about something like:

```
original_image = imread('original_image.jpg'); 
for n = 1:100
   imname = strcat('image_prefix',int2str(n),'.jpg');
   img=imread(imname);
   if isequal(size(original_image), size(img));
       DO COMPUTATIONS
   else
       delete(img);
   end
end
```

Of course you would substitute in whatever your image names and extensions are.